# Using generators to perform an inorder tree traversal on a BST

Tags: python, recursion, generator, binary-search-tree

So given the following:

```
def inorder(t):
    if t:
        inorder(t.left)
        yield t.key
        inorder(t.right)

x = [ n for n in inorder(r) ]
```

`x` only contains the root node, why?

Here's the full code; note that the BST implementation is correct, it's the `inorder()` implementation with generators that is somehow wrong.

```
class STree(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.key = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

def insert(r, node):
    if node.key < r.key:
        if r.left is None:
            r.left = node
        else:
            insert(r.left, node)
    else:
        if r.right is None:
            r.right = node
        else:
            insert(r.right, node)

def inorder(t):
    if t:
        inorder(t.left)
        yield t.key
        inorder(t.right)


r = STree(10)
insert(r, STree(12))
insert(r, STree(5))
insert(r, STree(99))
insert(r, STree(1))

tree = [ n for n in inorder(r) ]
print tree
```

Comment: Are you using python 2 or 3?

Comment: See the 3rd answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21175923/inorder-traversal-in-python). You are only actually yielding one value. If you are using python 3.3 onwards you can use `yield from`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`inorder(t.left)` only creates the generator object, it doesn't actually run it. You need to actually `yield` all the values produced by each of the sub-generators, like so:

```
def inorder(t):
    if t:
        yield from inorder(t.left)
        yield t.key
        yield from inorder(t.right)
```

Note that the `yield from` convenience syntax was only introduced in [Python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380) so if you're using an older version you'll have to iterate over the sub-generators explicitly:

```
# Python 2
def inorder(t):
    if t:
        for key in inorder(t.left):
            yield key
        yield t.key
        for key in inorder(t.right):
            yield key
```

Comment: I fixed a mistake on the py2 example; anyway thanks for the explanation, it makes much more sense now.

Comment: @laurids saw that, nice catch! and yw!

Comment: @Prerit both python2 and 3 versions work fine for me, your error must be somewhere else.

Comment: @tzaman It was python version. Leetcode has python version < 3.3 .

Comment: Careful about complexity here. Both the explicit loop and `yield from` lead to a quadratic-time algorithm here. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/#optimisations discusses the tree example specifically.

Answer (score 0):

There is python oneliner for a recursive tree in-order-traversal based on generator:

```
def inorderTr(r):
    yield from chain(inorderTr(r.left), (r.val,), inorderTr(r.right)) if r else ()
```

Original solution is published [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-inorder-traversal/solutions/4381521/one-line-solution/).